# How to pass in element into For-loop to run a function

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

It's been a while since I have asked a questions but I am needing help with what I think is a simple task.

I have a list of string values which I have passed into a loop. Each one of the strings pertains to a function of a parent package (in this case, QuantStats).

Code appears as follows:

```
import QuantStats as qs
list = ['avg_loss', 'avg_gain', 'best']

for l in list:
(>>) print(l)
(>>) print(qs.stats.l(df['returns']) (Error here - 'l' not recognised. no output)
```

For some reason the qs.stats.l line does not work. I am not sure how to reference each element in the list, such that the qs function can run.

Hopefully there is a simple work around? Any thoughts would be very much appreciated :) thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)

Comment: Here's a simple example: https://rextester.com/DQYW25147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the getattr() function to get the defined function. Like this:

```
import QuantStats as qs
list = ['avg_loss', 'avg_gain', 'best']

for l in list:
(>>) print(l)
(>>) print(getattr(qs.stats,l)(df['returns'])
```

Comment: Haha I didn't take note of the ,l and ran into trouble with attribution. Thank you for the suggestion! This solves my problem :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you entered 1 instead of `i` ,
It should be (`for i in List:`)

Comment: They used a lowercase `L` (`l`), not `1` (`i` never occurs anywhere). And the error isn't on the loop itself...